# Parent child relationships - my parent knows its children, but the children don't know the parent when they should

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parent

I'm working on an app that has book objects (RSEBook), each of which has an NSMutableArray of keyword objects (Keyword). The mutable array in the books is called 'keywords'

The method to add a child (Keyword) to the parent's array is:

> -(void)addTag:(Keyword *)word
>   {
>
> [keywords addObject:word];
>
> [word setParent:self];
>
> }

However, when this gets called in Document.m:

> -(IBAction)createKeyword:(id)sender{
>
> NSWindow *w = [tabView window];
>
> ```
> BOOL editingEnded = [w makeFirstResponder:w];
> if(!editingEnded) {
>     NSBeep();
>     return;
> }
>
> Keyword *k = [[Keyword alloc] init];  //Create a new keyword instance
>
> id current = [booksAC selectedObjects]; //NSArray of the selectedObjects (there will only ever be one object in the array as my table view hasn't got multi selection
>
> RSEBook *currBook = [current objectAtIndex:0]; //Get that object into currBook
>
> if (!currBook) {                              //Check that currBook = something
>     NSLog(@"current is nil");
> }
> ```

```
[currBook addTag:k];             //Add the object k as a tag to currBooks NSMutableArray 'keywords' this SHOULD set the parent, but it dosent (defined in RSEBook.h)


NSLog(@"The keywords parent: %@" ,[k parent]);  // this is always null for some reason
NSLog(@"parents keywords: %@", [currBook keywords]);  // this returns what I expect, a list of the books keywords
```

Comment: how do you implement `setParent:` is it a property?

Comment: Show the code for the Keyword class